# Skaffold doesn't accept "command" parameter in yaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm, skaffold

Here is the Skaffold yaml I'm using:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v1
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: myapp-api
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: elodie/myapp-api
    context: .
    docker:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
deploy:
  helm:
    releases:
    - name: elodie-api
      chartPath: bitnami/node
      remote: true
      setValues:
        command: ['/bin/bash', '-ec', 'npm start']
        image.repository: elodie/myapp-api
        service.type: LoadBalancer
        getAppFromExternalRepository: false
        applicationPort: 6666
      setValueTemplates:
        image.tag: "{{ .DIGEST_HEX }}"
```

I get `parsing skaffold config: error parsing skaffold configuration file: unable to parse config: yaml: unmarshal errors: line 16: cannot unmarshal !!seq into string` error when I add the command config but the value is taken straight out of the values.yaml that bitnami provides.

Why do I get this error, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`setValues` is turned into a sequence of `--set` arguments to `helm`.  So `setValues: only supports string values.

Helm does support ways to [represent other structures with `--set`](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of---set).  It looks like you should be able to use:

```
setValues:
  command: "{/bin/bash, -ec, npm start}"
```